# Interval timer vs database field for over-the-air updates?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to provide OTA updates to users. My app uses real-time listeners on the database, so my question is whether to:

1. Set a 15 minute interval timer to check if an update is available (requires network call and long timers)
2. Database field for each user specifying when update is required (2X write calls per user)
3. Check when app is launched or foregrounded (latter may occur multiple times in a single session, would have to add a refractory period)
4. Some hybrid or other solution

... or perhaps I am worried too much about some best practice / optimized solution when the end user experience is not really affected by whichever option I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is basically an implementation of option 3. If a user is constantly switching in and out of the app, it will wait 15 minutes after the last update check to check again.

- A useRef time variable that stores the last time the app was foregrounded
- An update function that checks for updates

  - If available: fetch update and reload app
- A useEffect to check for updates on launch
- A useEffect to listen to changes in AppState

  - If app was foregrounded && time.current + 15000 < Date.now(): check for updates